# Trigger update for a LiveData member when another LiveData is updated in the view model

Tags: android, viewmodel, observer-pattern, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

In a word game app I share a model between an activity and a fragment:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private LiveData<List<Game>> mGames;
    private final MutableLiveData<Game> mDisplayedGame = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

(please excuse the non-english text in the screenshot)

[image: activity and fragment]

**The activity** observes `mGames` being currently played by the user and updates the navigational drawer menu (see the left side of the above screenshot).

**The fragment** observes `mDisplayedGame` and displays it in a custom view (see the right side of the above screenshot).

**My problem** is that when the list of the games is updated at the server (and the activity receives new list of games via Websocket and stores it in the Room), I need to post an update to the fragment: "Hey, the game you are displaying was updated, redraw it!"

Is it possible to do that from within the shared view model?

I know that I could observe `mGames` in the fragment too and add a code there iterating through them and then finding out if the displayed game was updated at the server.

But I would prefer to do it in the `MainViewModel` because I have a feeling that the fragment should only observe the one game it is displaying and that's it.

**TL;DR**

Whenever `mGames` is updated in the view model via Room, I need to notify the `mDisplayedGame` observers too!

Comment: Take a look at `MediatorLiveData` (there's also some `Transformation` methods that might suffice as well....some of them I think just wrap `MediatorLiveData`).

Comment: `Transformations.switchMap` should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a MediatorLiveData for this.

The way it works is that

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final LiveData<List<Game>> mGames;
    private final MutableLiveData<Game> mSelectedGame = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private final MediatorLiveData<Game> mDisplayedGame = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    {
        mDisplayedGame.addSource(mGames, (data) -> {
            // find the new value of the selected game in the list
            mSelectedGame.setValue(newSelectedGame);
        });

        mDisplayedGame.addSource(mSelectedGame, (data) -> {
            mDisplayedGame.setValue(data);
        });
    }
```

And then you expose `mDisplayedGame` as a `LiveData<Game>` and it should just work.

Comment: Thank you, MediatorLiveData works now for me. Do you have an idea, how to [combine MediatorLiveData with Room calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804875/dao-method-returns-liststring-while-i-need-a-mapstring-integer), is it even possible? If I call DAO methods from `addSource`, should I wrap them in `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(...)`?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't answer this earlier, but yes, you do want to move DB queries to a background thread. You can use `postValue` to come back from them. Beware that you might have started a query, then received a new event emission, in which case you might want to ignore the results of the previously started query.

Comment: You want to keep the executor as a field reference though, instead of creating one each time.

Answer (score -3):

Use callback bro
-add a callback interface in your viewmodel and a setCallback method
-make your fragment implement it then call viewmodel.setCallback(fragment)
-call the callback in your obsever