# Dao method returns List<String> while I need a Map<String,Integer>

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

In an Android app using Architecture Components I have the following view model:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<List<String>> mUnchecked = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<List<String>> mChecked;

    public void setUnchecked(List<String> list) {
        mUnchecked.setValue(list);
    }

    public LiveData<List<String>> getChecked() { // OBSERVED BY A FRAGMENT
        return mChecked;
    }

    public MainViewModel(Application app) {
        super(app);
        mChecked = Transformations.switchMap(mUnchecked, 
                 list-> myDao().checkWords(list));
    }
```

The purpose of the above `switchMap` is to check, which of the words passed as a list of strings, do exist in a Room table:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word IN (:words)")
    LiveData<List<String>> checkWords(List<String> words);
```

The above code works well for me!

However I am stuck with wanting something slightly different -

Instead of the list of strings, I would prefer to pass a map of strings (words) -> integers (scores):

```
    public void setUnchecked(Map<String,Integer> map) {
        mUnchecked.setValue(map);
    }
```

The integers would be word scores in [my game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792203/trigger-update-for-a-livedata-member-when-another-livedata-is-updated-in-the-vie). And once the `checkWords()` has returned the results, I would like to set the scores to `null` for the words not found in the Room table and leave the other scores as they are.

The programming code would be easy (iterate through `mChecked.getValue()` and set to `null` for the words not found in the list returned by the DAO method) - but how to "marry" it with my `LiveData` members?

**TL;DR**

I would like to change my view model to hold maps instead of the lists:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Map<String,Integer>> mUnchecked = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<Map<String,Integer>> mChecked = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setUnchecked(Map<String,Integer> map) {
        mUnchecked.setValue(map);
    }

    public LiveData<Map<String,Integer>> getChecked() { // OBSERVED BY A FRAGMENT
        return mChecked;
    }

    public MainViewModel(Application app) {
        super(app);

        // HOW TO OBSERVE mUnchecked
        // AND RUN myDao().checkWords(new ArrayList<>(mUnchecked.getValue().keys()))
        // WRAPPED IN Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute( ... )
        // AND THEN CALL mChecked.postValue() ?
    }
```

How to achieve that please? Should I extend `MutableLiveData` or maybe use `MediatorLiveData` or maybe use `Transformations.switchMap()`?

**UPDATE:**

I will try the following tomorrow (today is too late in the evening) -

The Dao method I will change to return a list instead of `LiveData`:

```
@Query("SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word IN (:words)")
List<String> checkWords(List<String> words);
```

And then I will try to extend the `MutableLiveData`:

```
private final MutableLiveData<Map<String,Integer>> mChecked = new MutableLiveData<>();
private final MutableLiveData<Map<String,Integer>> mUnchecked = new MutableLiveData<Map<String,Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Map<String,Integer> uncheckedMap) {
        super.setValue(uncheckedMap);

        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(() -> {

            List<String> uncheckedList = new ArrayList<>(uncheckedMap.keySet());
            List<String> checkedList = WordsDatabase.getInstance(mApp).wordsDao().checkWords(uncheckedList);
            Map<String,Integer> checkedMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (String word: uncheckedList) {
                Integer score = (checkedList.contains(word) ? uncheckedMap.get(word) : null);
                checkedMap.put(word, score);
            }
            mChecked.postValue(checkedMap);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your algorithm. Are the keys of the "unchecked" `Map<String, Integer>` words? If so, then while I understand that you want to replace the `Integer` with `null` for words not returned by `checkWords()`, what do you want to happen for the words are *are* returned by `checkWords()`? Are you leaving the `Integer` alone? Or are you calculating a new value that just happens to not be `null`?

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question! Yes, exactly: the keys of the map are words and the values are scores formed by the words at the [Scrabble-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792203/trigger-update-for-a-livedata-member-when-another-livedata-is-updated-in-the-vie) game board. Once the existence of the words has been checked in the Room table, I'd like to replace the scores for invalid words with `null` and leave the other scores alone. I am considering extending `MutableLiveData`, not sure if that is correct path (please see the updated question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you have there in the update probably works, though I wouldn't create a new `Executor` for every `setValue()` call — create just one and hold onto it in your `MutableLiveData` subclass. Also, depending on your `minSdkVersion`, you might use some of the Java 8 stuff on `HashMap` (e.g., `replaceAll()`) to simplify the code a bit.

You could use `MediatorLiveData`, though in the end I think it would result in more code, not less. So, while from a purity standpoint `MediatorLiveData` is a better answer, that may not be a good reason for you to use it.

Frankly, this sort of thing isn't what `LiveData` is really set up for, IMHO. If this were my code that I were working on right now, I'd be using RxJava for the bulk of it, converting to `LiveData` in the end. And, I'd have as much of this as possible in a repository, rather than in a viewmodel. While your unchecked-to-checked stuff would be a tricky RxJava chain to work out, I'd still prefer it to the `MutableLiveData` subclass.

What EpicPandaForce suggests is an ideal sort of `LiveData`-only approach, though I don't think he is implementing your algorithm quite correctly, and I am skeptical that it can be adapted easily to your desired algorithm.

In the end, though, the decision kinda comes down to: who is going to see this code?

- If this code is for your eyes only, or will live in a dusty GitHub repo that few are likely to look at, then if you feel that you can maintain the `MutableLiveData` subclass, we can't really complain.
- If this code is going to be reviewed by co-workers, ask your co-workers what they think.
- If this code is going to be reviewed by prospective employers... consider RxJava. Yes, it has a learning curve, but for the purposes of getting interest from employers, they will be more impressed by you knowing how to use RxJava than by you knowing how to hack `LiveData` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky question!

If we check the source code for `Transformations.switchMap`, we see that:

1.) it wraps the provided live data with a MediatorLiveData

2.) if the wrapped live data emits an event, then it invokes a function that receives the new value of wrapped live data, and returns a "new" live data of a different type

3.) if the "new" live data of a different type differs from the previous one, then the observer of the previous one is removed, and it's added to the new one instead (so that you only observe the newest LiveData and don't accidentally end up observing an old one)

With that in mind, I think we can chain your switchMap calls and create a new LiveData whenever `myDao().checkWords(words)` changes.

```
LiveData<List<String>> foundInDb = Transformations.switchMap(mWords, words -> myDao().checkWords(words));
LiveData<Map<String, Integer>> found = Transformations.switchMap(foundInDb, (words) -> {
    MutableLiveData<Map<String, Integer>> scoreMap = new MutableLiveData<>();
    // calculate the score map from `words` list
    scoreMap.setValue(map);
    return scoreMap;
});
this.mFound = found;
```

Please verify if what I'm telling you is correct, though.

Also if there are a bunch of words, consider using some async mechanism and `scoreMap.postValue(map)`.

Comment: Thanks I've tried that and got nowehere. Can't I just have two `MutableLiveData<Map<String,Integer>>` members in my view model? And when one's value is set, run `myDao().checkWords(new ArrayList<>(...keys()))` wrapped in a `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(...)` and `postValue` to the other one?